# How to search dependencies in IntelliJ's Project Structure > Modules > Dependencies tab

Tags: jakarta-ee, intellij-idea

While on the Dependency tab in IntelliJ > Project Structure > Modules > Dependencies, is there a way to search for part of a dependency name and then press a key to search for the next match?

The Java EE project I'm working on has many dependencies, some of which must be at the top of the dependency list.  Each time we do an re-import of a POM file the dependencies are rearranged and we need to go through the list and restore the order.  This is time consuming because the files we are looking for all end in -1.6. There are 3 of them in our case and I haven't found a way to use the find to find the next item in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the down arrow on your keyboard to move to the next match after you have typed in your search term. It'll move to the next dependency that matches your search. This same arrow key navigation works anywhere that you can do text searching (as far as I have seen).

Comment: This is how I thought it should work, but when I searched for 1.6 it didn't seem to work.  After reading your comment I tried again and looked more closely at the results and found that the 1.6 is actually a regular expression.  It was searching for any dependencies that had "1" followed by any number of characters followed by "6" which turns out to be a lot of them.  So, in actuality, the arrow key does jump to the next one.  I just have to be careful when using regular expression sequences.  Thank you.

Comment: Oh good catch, I didn't know it searched with regular expressions by default.